# How to host a discord bot in heroku(error)

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

im trying to host a discord bot on heroku but I have this error.

[Link to the photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6X91.png)

I have the last version of discord.js and Node.js

My procfile is like this

```
worker: node ./src/index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is using old version of node.js, that's why you can see this error! You can't update this version sadly, so there is no real solution for you

Comment: So no more heroku hosting for discord bots??

Comment: @JuanGarcia djs v11 and v12 code works fine but no v13 sadly

Answer (score 2):

To fix that error you should to use npx at first and then node

```
worker: npx node ./src/index.js
```

or

```
worker: npx node .
```

It should to work.